# Getting map location Python

Tags: python, google-maps, geolocation

Is there any way to get the computer geolocation (as in Google Maps "My Location") from a Python script? The computer would always be connected to the Internet.

Comment: there are api services that can do this that you can talkto using urllib or something

Comment: That's what I am asking, what are the services that I can use? Or how can I access Google Maps api

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> import re,requests
>>> raw = requests.get('http://www.geoiptool.com/').text
>>> latlon = re.search("GPoint\(([^)]+)\)",raw).groups(0)
>>> lat,lon = map(float,latlon[0].split(","))
>>> print "Latitude:%s   Longitude:%s"%(lat,lon)
Latitude:-117.2455   Longitude:46.7322
```

a couple of caveats ...

1. This probably is not the best method and should not be done over and over again or you might upset the site owners
2. this uses IP lookups so it may not be as good as GPS/wifi coordinates

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked as I wanted. Thanks as well for the tips.

Answer (score 0):

Google Maps license do not allow using geocoding service API outside map object. Look at this question https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/18871/is-there-an-open-source-geocoding-tool-which-can-be-used-commercially. Hope it helps.